# Change UserControl on button click (navigation without reloading entire page?)

Tags: c#, xaml, navigation, windows-phone-8.1

I want to navigate between usercontrols by clicking button (I don't want to reload entire page)

I have grind in which i have blank usercontrol

```
<Grid x:Name="Content" Grid.Row="1" Background="#FF1A7E1F">
    <UserControl x:Name="MainConent"/>                    
</Grid>
```

and i want programaticly to set this usercontrol to existing one e.g.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainConent.Equals(new MainControl()); // maincontrol is a usercontrol
}
```

but sadly this doesn't work .... is there any way to navigate without need to reload entire page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Have you even checked the purpose of `Equals`?

First you have to remove the current content of `Grid`, then set new content.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Content.Children.Clear();
    Content.Children.Add(new MainControl());
}
```

Comment: yeah right ... i did not check the purpose of equal ;/ but thanks for help - i was almost sure i could do it another way around